# Calculating: $\sum_{s=0}^\infty\sum_{t=0}^s e^{-3}st\frac{1}{t!}\frac{2^{s-t}}{(s-t)!}$

Tags: calculus, probability, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, summation

After a considerable time of trying to calculate the following:
$$\sum_{s=0}^\infty\sum_{t=0}^s e^{-3}st\frac{1}{t!}\frac{2^{s-t}}{(s-t)!}$$
Assuming 0≤t≤s.I succeeded to reach an answer by using the binomial distribution:
$$e^{-3}\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\frac{3^ss}{s!}\sum_{t=0}^{s}t{s\choose t}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^t\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{s-t}$$ When I keep in mind that the inner sum represents the expectation value of a binomial random variable $X$. $E[X]=\sum_{t=0}^{s}t{s\choose t}(\frac{1}{3})^t(\frac{2}{3})^{s-t}=\frac{s}{3}$:
$$e^{-3}\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\frac{3^ss^2}{3(s!)}=e^{-3}\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\frac{3^s}{s!}(s+1)=e^{-3}\left(\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}3\frac{3^{s-1}}{(s-1)!}+\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\frac{3^s}{s!}\right)=4$$
However, I'd like to know how I can reach the same result without using the binomial distribution. I tried using substitution, but something just didn't work out.

Comment: @xpaul I added some clarification regarding this issue. It's not defined for s<t, which means whenever that is the case, I interpret it as 0, or I just change the starting index.

Comment: Any proof of the expectation value of the binomial distribution will answer your question  no?

Comment: @Thomas I guess it will get me acquainted with this type of sum expression, but If I were to calculate this sum without referring to the expectation value of a binomial distribution, is there a "calculus" way of reaching the answer? I believe the proof will have the answer though. If you could refer me to a source I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{s=0}^\infty\sum_{t=0}^s e^{-3}st\frac{1}{t!}\frac{2^{s-t}}{(s-t)!}
&= e^{-3}\sum_{t=0}^\infty \frac{t}{t!} \sum_{s=t}^\infty s \frac{2^{s-t}}{(s-t)!} \\
&= e^{-3}\sum_{t=1}^\infty \frac{t}{t!} \sum_{s=0}^\infty (s+t) \frac{2^s}{s!} \\
&= e^{-3}\sum_{t=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(t-1)!} \left(\sum_{s=0}^\infty s\frac{2^s}{s!} + t \sum_{s=0}^\infty \frac{2^s}{s!}\right) \\
&= e^{-3}\sum_{t=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(t-1)!} \left(2\sum_{s=1}^\infty \frac{2^{s-1}}{(s-1)!} + t \sum_{s=0}^\infty \frac{2^s}{s!}\right) \\
&= e^{-3}\sum_{t=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(t-1)!} (2+t)e^2 \\
&= e^{-1}\sum_{t=1}^\infty \frac{t-1+3}{(t-1)!} \\
&= e^{-1}\left(\sum_{t=1}^\infty \frac{t-1}{(t-1)!} + \sum_{t=1}^\infty \frac{3}{(t-1)!}\right)\\
&= e^{-1}(e + 3e)\\
&= 4
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
\begin{align}
S
&=e^{-3}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{\ell=0}^k\frac{\ell}{\ell!}\frac{2^{k-\ell}}{(k-\ell)!}k\\
&=e^{-3}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{\ell=0}^k\frac{\ell}{\ell!}\frac{2^{k-\ell}}{(k-\ell)!}(\ell+k-\ell)\\
&=e^{-3}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{\ell=0}^k\frac{\ell^2}{\ell!}\frac{2^{k-\ell}}{(k-\ell)!}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{\ell=0}^k\frac{\ell}{\ell!}\frac{2^{k-\ell}}{(k-\ell)!}(k-\ell)\right).
\end{align}
$$
Now use the definition of the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) of series to get
$$
\begin{align}
S
&=e^{-3}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k^2}{k!}\times\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2^k}{k!}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k}{k!}\times\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2^k\cdot k}{k!}\right)\\
&=e^{-3}\left(2e\times e^2+e\times2e^2\right)\\
&=4.
\end{align}
$$